# Establecer conexión con módulo HM-10 con smartphone mediante bluetooth

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

pues como bien indica el título quiero establecer conexión con módulo HM-10 con smartphone mediante bluetooth, pero cuando se está vinculando me salta un mensaje que dice: "No se ha podido establecer comunicación con HM-10", lo he probado con dos smarthphone y en los dos me salta el mismo error. Tengo que decir que la configuración está hecha en arduino

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8); // RX, TX
// Connect HM10      Arduino Uno
//   Pin 1/TXD      Pin 7
//   Pin 2/RXD      Pin 8


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
 }

  void loop() {
  char c=mensaje;

  if (Serial.available()) {
   c = Serial.read();
    mySerial.print(c);
  }
if (mySerial.available()) {
c = mySerial.read();
Serial.print(c); 
 }
}
```

Tambien he probado a escribir solo

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8); // RX, TX
// Connect HM10      Arduino Uno
//   Pin 1/TXD      Pin 7
//   Pin 2/RXD      Pin 8


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
 }

  void loop() {
  String mensaje="Conexión establecida\n";

  Serial.println(mensaje);


 }
}
```

Este último código escribe en el monitor de arduino, pero cuando me quiero conectar a él me sigue saliendo el mensaje anterior

Mi pregunta: ¿A qué se puede deber que no se puede vincular el módulo HM-10 con el smartphone?

PD: Utlilizo la app "Blue term" para poder leer el mensaje que envía, ya que lo he probado con el módulo HC-06 y me funciona perfectamente, es sólo con el HM-10 con el que no se puede conectar

Comment: Solucionaste algo? yo estoy en el mismo problema que tu: A mi me aparece: Sincronización rechazada por (nombre del bluetooth). Tengo un Xiaomi Redmi3 y pensaba que era por eso, pero lo he probado con otros móviles y tampoco deja conectarse. Aunque con la aplicación Ble Scanner si y al ordenador también me deja conectarlo.